# How to guarantee the combiner run at least once in map/reduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

From some articles,I know combiner will run in mapper-side and reducer-side,and it will run 0~N times. And I know our mapreduce program should get same result whether or not the combiner invoked.

But I have one special situation that need the combiner will be called at least once,does anyone know how to make sure that?

PS,In `maptask.java`,I saw the line:

```
if (null == combinerClass || numSpills < minSpillsForCombine) {
    Merger.writeFile(kvIter, writer, reporter);
} else {
    combineCollector.setWriter(writer);
    combineAndSpill(kvIter, combineInputCounter);
}
```

If I set **minSpillsForCombine** to zero,can I make sure the combiner will be called at least once?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the combiner to run at least once, you're misusing the combiner. Its role is one that is strictly optional, collapsing values that have an associative/commutative nature. If you said more about why, it might be possible to suggest a better design.

Answer (score 3):

- During a spill, before the spilling thread writes to disk, the thread first divides the data into **partitions** corresponding to the reducers that they will ultimately be sent to.
- Within each partition, the background thread performs an in-memory sort by key, and **if there is a combiner function, it is run on the output of the sort**.
- If there are at least three spill files, the combiner is **run again** before the output file is written.
- You can change this magic number 3 by overriding the property : **mapreduce.map.combine.minspills**
- Combiners may be run repeatedly over the input without affecting the final result.
- If there are only one or two spills, **the potential reduction in map output size is not worth the overhead in invoking the combiner**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but I do not think the combiner is guaranteed to run, even if one exists.